# zyBooks 1.20.2 Tree Height

Tags: python

Given variables `angle_elev` and `shadow_len` that represent the angle of elevation and the shadow length of a tree, respectively, assign `tree_height` with the height of the tree.

Ex: If the input is:
3.8
17.5
then the output is:
Tree height: 13.5372315838047
Note: tree_height = tan(angle_elev) * shadow_len

```
import math

tree_height = 0.0

angle_elev  = float(input())
shadow_len  = float(input())

tree_height = math.tan((angle_elev) * shadow_len)

print('Tree height:', tree_height)
```

Comment: The parentheses should be placed only around 'angle_elev'. so Instead of tree_height = math.tan((angle_elev) * shadow_len), it should be tree_height = math.tan(angle_elev) * shadow_len

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The variables are given, all you have to do is input them and apply the function `math.tan` to `angle_elev`, then multiply with `shadow_len`.

```py
import math

tree_height = 0.0

angle_elev  = float(input())
shadow_len  = float(input())

tree_height = math.tan(angle_elev) * shadow_len


print('Tree height:', tree_height)
```

Note the order of execution in this code, `math.tan` is called on `angle_elev`, then the result is multiplied with `shadow_len`, whereas in your code, the multiplication happens first, then the function call.